# WORDPRESS ERROR: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress

I was editing my wordpress page and I didn't do anything unusual, but suddenly my HomePage lost background color (Now borders are white but the middle of the page is how it should be).

My console keeps throwing me this:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined

at HTMLButtonElement. (ajax-filter-posts.js?ver=1:57)
at HTMLDivElement.dispatch (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:3)

at HTMLDivElement.r.handle (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:3)

at Object.trigger (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:3)

at Object.a.event.trigger (jquery-migrate.min.js?ver=1.4.1:2)

at HTMLButtonElement. (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:3)

at Function.each (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2)

at a.fn.init.each (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2)

at a.fn.init.trigger (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:3)
    at HTMLDivElement. (ajax-filter-posts.js?ver=1:76)

what to do? My **ajax-filter-posts.js?ver=1:57** looks like this:

```
(function($) {
$doc = $(document);
$doc.ready( function() {
    /*Retrieve posts*/
    var container = $('.container-async');
    container.each(function() {
        var $movie_tab_id = $(this).attr('id'),
            $movie_tab = "#" + $movie_tab_id,
            $content = $($movie_tab).find('.category-content.flw');
        function get_posts($params) {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: blockter.ajax_url,
                data: {
                    action: 'do_filter_posts',
                    nonce: blockter.nonce,
                    params: $params
                },
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
                    if (data.status === 200) {
                        $content.html(data.content);
                    }
                    else if (data.status === 201) {
                        $content.html(data.message);
                    }
                },
                error: function(MLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {

                },
                complete: function(data, textStatus) {

                    msg = textStatus;

                    if (textStatus === 'success') {
                        msg = data.responseJSON.found;
                    }

                    $content.removeClass('loading');
                }
            });
        }

        $($movie_tab).on('click', 'button[data-filter], .category-pagination li a', function(event) {
            if(event.preventDefault) { event.preventDefault(); }
            var $this = $(this),
                $mediaType = null;
            /*Set filter active*/
            if ($this.data('filter')) {
                $this.addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
                $page = $this.data('page');
                $mediaType = $this.data('media');
                $postin = $this.data('postin');
            }
            else {
                /*Pagination*/
                $page = parseInt(($this.attr('href').replace(/\D/g,''));
                $mediaType = $this.parent().data('media');
                $postin = $this.parent().data('postin');
                $this = $('.category-filter button.active');
            }
            $content.addClass('loading');
            $content.append('<div class="ajaxloading"></div>');
            $params = {
                'page' : $page,
                'tax'  : $this.data('filter'),
                'term' : $this.data('term'),
                'qty'  : $this.closest($($movie_tab)).data('paged'),
                'media': $mediaType,
                'postin': $this.data('postin'),
            };

            /*Run query*/
            get_posts($params);
        });
        $('button[data-term="all-terms"]').trigger('click');
    });

    var $movie_tab_id = $('.container-async').attr('id'),
    $movie_tab = "#" + $movie_tab_id,
    $content = $($movie_tab).find('.category-content.flw'),
    $contents = $($movie_tab).find('.category-content.specific');

    $($movie_tab).on('click', 'button[data-filter], .category-pagination li a', function(event) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: blockter.ajax_url,
            data: {
                action: 'do_filter_posts',
                nonce: blockter.nonce,
                params: $params
            },
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
                if (data.status === 200) {
                    $content.html(data.content);
                    $contents.html(data.content);
                }
                else if (data.status === 201) {
                    $content.html(data.message);    
                    $contents.html(data.message);   
                }
            },
            error: function(MLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {

            },
            complete: function(data, textStatus) {

                msg = textStatus;

                if (textStatus === 'success') {
                    msg = data.responseJSON.found;
                }

                $content.removeClass('loading');
                $contents.removeClass('loading');
            }
        });
        $contents.addClass('loading');
        $contents.append('<div class="ajaxloading"></div>');

    });
});
})(jQuery);
```

my **$movie_tab.php** looks like this:

```html
<?php
$atts = vc_map_get_attributes( $this->getShortcode(), $atts );
extract( $atts );

$class_to_filter = '';
$class_to_filter .= vc_shortcode_custom_css_class( $inline_css, ' ' ) . $this->getExtraClass( $class ) . $this->getCSSAnimation( $css_animation );
$all_class = apply_filters( VC_SHORTCODE_CUSTOM_CSS_FILTER_TAG, $class_to_filter, $this->settings['base'], $atts );

/*set columns*/
global $post;
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'ht_movie',
);

$query = new WP_Query();
$query->query( $args );
if ( ! $query ) {
    return;
}
?>
<?php if( $query->have_posts() ): ?>
    <?php
    switch ($data) {
        case 'collections':
            $a = array(
                'tax'      => 'mv_collection', // Taxonomy
                'terms'    => $data_collections, // Get specific taxonomy terms only
                'active'   => false, // Set active term by ID
                'per_page' => $movie_per_tab // How many posts per page
            );
            break;
        case 'casts':
            $a = array(
                'tax'      => 'mv_actor', // Taxonomy
                'terms'    => $data_casts, // Get specific taxonomy terms only
                'active'   => false, // Set active term by ID
                'per_page' => $movie_per_tab // How many posts per page
            );
            break;
        default:
            $a = array(
                'tax'      => 'mv_genre', // Taxonomy
                'terms'    => $data_generes, // Get specific taxonomy terms only
                'active'   => false, // Set active term by ID
                'per_page' => $movie_per_tab // How many posts per page
            );
    }
    ?>

    <?php
        $tab_id = uniqid('tabid-');
        $drop_id = uniqid('dropid-');
    ?>
    
    <div class="flw container-async" id="<?php echo esc_attr( $tab_id ); ?>" data-paged="<?php echo esc_attr($a['per_page']); ?>">
        <?php  $terms  = get_terms($a['tax']); 
                $term_curr = $a['terms'];   
                $items = explode(',',$term_curr);
        ?>
        <?php if($term_curr == ''): ?>
            <div class="category-filter flw">
                <button data-filter="<?php echo esc_attr($terms[0]->taxonomy); ?>" data-term="all-terms" data-page="1" data-media="movie" class="active"><?php esc_html_e('All', 'blockter'); ?></button>
                <?php foreach ($terms as $term) : ?>
                <button data-filter="<?php echo esc_attr($term->taxonomy); ?>" data-term="<?php echo esc_attr($term->slug); ?>" data-page="1" data-media="movie"><?php echo esc_html($term->name); ?></button>            
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </div>
            <!--for mobile version-->
            <div class="filter-cate-mobile" id="<?php echo esc_attr($drop_id);?>">
    <div class="flex-parent-cate">
     <div class="category-filter flw dropdown">
      <button class="dropbtn"  data-page="1"><?php echo esc_html__("SORT BY", 'blockter'); ?></button>
      <ul class="dropdown-content">
       <li><button data-filter="<?php echo esc_attr($terms[0]->taxonomy); ?>" data-term="all-terms" data-page="1" data-media="movie"><?php esc_html_e('All', 'blockter'); ?></button></li>
       <?php foreach ($terms as $term) : ?>
                                <li><button data-filter="<?php echo esc_attr($term->taxonomy); ?>" data-term="<?php echo esc_attr($term->slug); ?>" data-page="1" data-media="movie"><?php echo esc_html($term->name); ?></button></li>
       <?php endforeach; ?>
      </ul>
              </div>
    </div>
   </div>
            <div class="category-content flw"></div>
        <?php else: ?>
            <div class="category-filter flw">
                <button data-filter="<?php echo esc_attr($terms[0]->taxonomy); ?>" data-term="all-terms" data-page="1" data-media="movie" class="active"><?php esc_html_e('All', 'blockter'); ?></button>
                <?php foreach ($items as $item) : ?>
                    <?php if($data == 'generes'): ?>
                        <button  data-filter="<?php echo esc_attr('mv_genre'); ?>" data-term="<?php echo esc_attr($item); ?>" data-media="movie"><?php echo esc_html($item); ?></button>
                    <?php elseif($data == 'collections'): ?>
                        <button  data-filter="<?php echo esc_attr('mv_collection'); ?>" data-term="<?php echo esc_attr($item); ?>" data-media="movie"><?php echo esc_html($item); ?></button>
                    <?php else: ?>
                        <button  data-filter="<?php echo esc_attr('mv_actor'); ?>" data-term="<?php echo esc_attr($item); ?>" data-media="movie"><?php echo esc_html($item); ?></button>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </div>
            <!--for mobile version-->
   <div class="filter-cate-mobile" id="<?php echo esc_attr($drop_id);?>" >
    <div class="flex-parent-cate">
     <div class="category-filter flw dropdown">
      <button class="dropbtn" data-page="1"><?php echo esc_html__("SORT BY", 'blockter'); ?></button>
      <ul class="dropdown-content">
       <li><button data-filter="<?php echo esc_attr($terms[0]->taxonomy); ?>" data-term="all-terms" data-page="1" data-media="movie"><?php esc_html_e('All', 'blockter'); ?></button></li>
       <?php foreach ($items as $item) : ?>
                                <?php if($data == 'generes'): ?>
                                <li><button data-filter="<?php echo esc_attr('mv_genre'); ?>" data-term="<?php echo esc_attr($item); ?>" data-media="movie"><?php echo esc_html($item); ?></button></li>
                                <?php elseif($data == 'collections'): ?>
                                <li><button data-filter="<?php echo esc_attr('mv_collection'); ?>" data-term="<?php echo esc_attr($item); ?>" data-media="movie"><?php echo esc_html($item); ?></button></li>
                            <?php else: ?>
                                <li><button data-filter="<?php echo esc_attr('mv_actor'); ?>" data-term="<?php echo esc_attr($item); ?>" data-media="movie"><?php echo esc_html($item); ?></button></li>
                                <?php endif; ?>
       <?php endforeach; ?>
      </ul>
              </div>
    </div>
   </div> 
            <div class="category-content flw"></div>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>    
<?php 
    endif;
?>
```

Comment: sounds like `$this.attr('href')` is returning `undefined`

Comment: I know, but I don't know how to fix this, that's why I asked here @epascarello

Comment: So debug and figure out what is up. `console.log(this)`, is it what you expect it to be? There is way too much code for us to look over. And since it is php markup, we can not really run it to help you out or see what the JS is running against.

Comment: Your code seems to assume that within `$movie_tab`, if the click event is not triggered by a `button[data-filter]` its from a pagination anchor button. From this line `$page = parseInt(($this.attr('href').replace(/\D/g,''));` it looks like there is no `href` attribute found in your `.category-pagination li a` selector.